# How to Convert Pandas fillna Function with mean into SQL (Snowflake)?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem**

I'm converting a Python Pandas data pipeline into a series of views in Snowflake. The transformations are mostly straightforward, but some of them seem to be more difficult in SQL. I'm wondering if there are straightforward methods.

**Question**

How can I write a Pandas `fillna(df['col'].mean())` as simply as possible using SQL?

**Example**

Here's a sample dataframe with the result I'm looking for:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'somenull':[0, 0, 1, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan]})
>>> df['nonull']=df['somenull'].fillna(df['somenull'].mean())
>>> df
   somenull  nonull
0       0.0     0.0
1       0.0     0.0
2       1.0     1.0
3       3.0     3.0
4       5.0     5.0
5       NaN     1.8
6       NaN     1.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in SQL too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(somecol float);
INSERT INTO tab(somecol) VALUES (0.0), (0.0), (1),(3),(5),(NULL),(NULL);
```

Here using COALESCE and windowed AVG:

```
SELECT somecol, COALESCE(somecol, AVG(somecol) OVER()) As nonull FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]